# How often do websphere process or application servers need to be restarted?

Tags: websphere, application-server

am a system admin. my boss is asking us to reboot production IBM WebSphere process or application server every week. I understand that, it was a good practice to reboot server often long back release stale connections etc.

But, i believe now all the software has become robust/reliable. I do not think, reboot is needed every week. (I personally prefer, reboot when needed)

Please provide your suggestions.

thank you.

Comment: i'm planning to prepare shell scripts to automate reboot  of websphere weekly (non-prod followed by prod)

Comment: Servers should never need to be rebooted regularly.

Comment: If your servers **need** to be rebooted regularly to keep them running properly then they're broken.

Answer (score 1):

There is no **need** nor recommendation, unless you're aware a specific (and slow) resource leak.  It might be someones overall opinion that this is  the way software should be managed, but it's nothing intrinsic to WebSphere Application Server.